# Uncountable models of set theory

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

Assume we have a countable transitive model of set theory which satisfies some set of first-order axioms $T$.

Is it possible to get from this a model $\mathcal{M}$ of set theory which satisfies the following:

1. $\mathcal{M}$ contains $\omega_1$ and $\omega_1^\mathcal{M}=\omega_1$, so in particular it contains all countable sequences of integers;
2. $\mathcal{M}$ satisfies the theory $T$;
3. $\mathcal{M}$ is well-founded and transitive.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of a question of mine. It is consistent that there are countable transitive models, but no uncountable transitive models at all. So the answer is no.

Comment: Ok, fine. Case closed.